# print unique numbers from a sorted list python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print all elements in a sorted list that only occur *once*.

My code below works but I'm sure there is a better way:

```
def print_unique(alist):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if i < (len(alist)-1):
            if alist[i] == alist[i+1]:
                i+=1
                if alist[i] == alist[i-1]:
                    i+=1
            elif  alist[i] == alist[i-1]:
                  i+=1    
            else:
              print alist[i]
        else:
            if alist[-1]!= alist[-2]:
                print alist[-1]

randomlist= [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,11,12,14,42]
print_unique(randomlist)
```

This produces

```
1
2
5
6
9
11
12
14
42
```

e.g. all values that only appear once in a row.

Comment: Martijn's code is very efficient, but (like your code) it does assume that `alist` is already sorted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP's results only includes items that are not duplicates. Too bad the question was not well delivered. So the link to the dupe does not actually solve their problem.  A slightly modified extension of the solution you proposed does it:  `print [k for k, g in groupby(randomlist) if len(list(g)) == 1]`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: right, yes, and the OP was entirely to blame by not including a clear problem statement.

Comment: @PM2Ring: that's what the title says can be assumed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`itertools.groupby()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your inputs and filter on groups that are one element long:

```
from itertools import groupby

def print_unique(alist):
    for elem, group in groupby(alist):
        if sum(1 for _ in group) == 1:  # count without building a new list
            print elem
```

or if you want to do it 'manually', track the last item seen and if you have seen it more than once:

```
def print_unique(alist, _sentinel=object()):
    last, once = _sentinel, False
    for elem in alist:
        if elem == last:
            once = False
        else:
            if once:
                print last
            last, once = elem, True
    if last is not _sentinel and once:
        print last
```

You may want to replace the `print` statements with `yield` and leave printing to the caller:

```
def filter_unique(alist):
    for elem, group in groupby(alist):
        if sum(1 for _ in group) == 1:  # count without building a new list
            yield elem

for unique in filter_unique(randomlist):
    print unique
```

Answer (score -1):

This question seems to have duplicates.

If you do not wish to preserve the order of your list, you can do

```
print list(set(sample_list))
```

You can also try,

```
unique_list = []
for i in sample_list:
    if i not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(i)
```

EDIT:

In order to print all the elements in the list so that they appear once in a row, you can try this

```
print '\n'.join([str(i) for i in unique_list])
```

And, as @martijn-pieters mentioned it in the comments, the first code was found to be very fast compared to the second one, when I did a small benchmark. On a list of 10^5 elements, the second code took 63.66 seconds to complete whereas the first one took a mere 0.2200 seconds. (on a list generated using `random.random()`)

Comment: So don't answer, flag as a duplicate. And your second solution takes O(NK) time as the `unique_list` is scanned again and again to test membership.

Comment: I still like this answer, pretty sure the OP can learn alot from it

Comment: Thanks for the info, @martijn-pieters. But, I cannot mark it as duplicate with my current reputation :)

Comment: You only need 15 points to [flag posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: @PM2Ring: but more to flag as duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, ok. I should have read the fine print. :oops:

Comment: Sorry for the misleading info in my previous comment, Amal. OTOH, even when you don't have sufficient rep to flag as duplicate, you can still do a search for dupe targets and post a link in a comment. Sure, it's not as good as a dupe flag, but it still lets potential answerers know that the question may be a dupe, and it assists those who _do_ have sufficient rep to flag or close-vote dupes.

Comment: BTW the specs of the problem have changed slightly since you wrote your answer.

Answer (score -3):

you can do by this:

```
print (set(YOUR_LIST))
```

or if you need a list use this:

```
print (list(set(YOUR_LIST)))
```

Answer (score -4):

Sets are lists containing unique items. If you construct a set from the array, it will contain only the unique items:

```
def print_unique(alist):
   print set( alist )
```

The input list does not need to be sorted.